# How to use a different toolbar for each page with Polymer app elements

Tags: polymer-1.0, polymer-cli

I am trying to create an app using Polymer `app elements`, based on the `polymer-cli` application generated using the `app-drawer-template`.

The problem I have is that I want to use a different `app-header` in each child page but I can't seem to make that work.

I have tried moving the `<app-header>` into the child pages, it kind of works but the `drawer-toggle` `<paper-icon-button>` is permanently shown.

Is there a way to get the app header drawer to toggle correctly from child pages?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:-

https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/255

```html
<iron-pages selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  ...
  <app-header-layout name="view1">
    <app-header>
    </app-header>
   <my-view1></my-view1>
  </app-header-layout>
  ...
</iron-pages>
```